# AttributeError: expected a callback function (and optionally one or two strings) as argument(s)

Tags: python, callback, blender, attributeerror

I'm new to Python and was trying to do some import and export scripting in Blender 2.43(which uses Python 2.4).
I had a simple script:

```
import Blender
import flt_import 
import export_obj
import os


select_file=flt_import.select_file(r'C:\Code\Code\Testing4Flt\sg_navysoldier.flt')
Blender.Window.FileSelector(select_file, "Import OpenFlight", "*.flt")
out_file=export_obj.write_ui(r'C:\Code\Code\Testing4Flt\sg_navysoldier.obj')
Blender.Window.FileSelector(out_file,'Export Wavefront OBJ', sys.makename(ext='.obj'))
```

When run, I got the error in the title at line 8. I don't really understand what it means and I tried searching it but couldn't find that error exactly. Will appreciate any help.

Edit:

Here's the full traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "Testing4.py", line 8, in ?
AttributeError:
expected a callback function (and optionally one or two strings) as argument(s)
```

Comment: Post the full traceback

Comment: @Barmar Hi I edited it in.

Comment: That doesn't look like the full traceback. Where are all the calls between "Traceback (most recent call last)" and "File ..."

Comment: First you said the error is on line 7, but the traceback says line 8. Which call is actually getting the error?

Comment: I edited my code a little and forgot to change it to 8. As for the traceback, this is all I can see in my console (https://imgur.com/a/hY5Xvuo).

Comment: Which line is line 8?

Comment: @Barmar Blender.Window.FileSelector(select_file, "Import OpenFlight", "*.flt")

Comment: The first argument is supposed to be a function. The function is called with the selected filename as the argument. You're selecting the file with `flt_import.select_file()`, you can't pass the selected file as an argument to `FileSelector()`.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use the file selector there if you've already selected the file on the previous line?